# Content presenter inside user control

Tags: silverlight

I'm developing my custom menu. It behaves like this. I have one toggle button and pathListBox that positioning menu items (buttons) into circle. So I have Menu user control that contains toggle button and one pathListBox. So I don't know how to put menu items inside pathListBox. I want to write

```
 <my:Menu>
    <my:MenuItem>
    </my:MenuItem>
</my:Menu>
```

How to get this content of the user control into pathListBox.

Tnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider building a true Control or ItemsControl; UserControl derives from ContentControl and is not well-suited to building controls with many items being presented.